# PHP pthreads examples when executed through CLI works properly on IIS7 not through WEB

Tags: php, iis-7, pthreads

I have followed these steps:

1. Installed php-5.4.25-Win32-VC9-x86 thread safe version
2. Downloaded pthreads-0.38-php-5.4 and:

   •Added pthreadVC2.dll (included with the Windows releases) to the same directory as php.exe eg.C:\php

   •Added php_pthreads.dll to PHP extention folder eg. C:\php\ext

   •Added extension=php_pthreads.dll in C:\php\php.ini
3. Checked phpinfo() it results in Thread safety enabled and pthreads version 0.38-rc
4. When executed the sample thread script through command line interface on windowsNT IIS7 2008 R2
   c:\php>php.exe -f c:\somedir\filetest.php
   it runs succesfully and i get the result.
5. I tried to run same example of thread through browser but it showed 500 internal server error.

Comment: more information would be handy, is there anything in error logs ?? it's probably the case that IIS cannot load pthreadVC2.dll ... but that's a stab in the dark ...